# How make font in TextView more thinner?

Tags: android

I want to make font in **TextView** more thinner. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in android only four fonttype-face

**TypeFace**

```
Typeface.DEFAULT
Typeface.MONOSPACE
Typeface.SANS_SERIF
Typeface.SERIF
```

and **font-type**

```
Typeface.NORMAL
Typeface.BOLD
Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC
Typeface.ITALIC
```

you can use like as

```
textView.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT, Typeface.BOLD);
```

and other way is you can download any **.ttf file** and put it in asset folder and use like as this

```
Typeface type=Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),
        "DroidSansMono.ttf");
textView.setTypeface(type, null);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this using a fontFamily:

From xml:

```
android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
```

Programmatically

```
textView.setTypeface(Typeface.create("sans-serif-light", Typeface.NORMAL));
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this attribute in your layout xml?

```
android:height="10dp" //Use as many pixel as you want here
```

Comment: I want to save old height and make the font more thinner. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

you can use another typeface as well if you want:

```
android:typeface="monospace"
```

or increase the size of the text :

```
android:textSize="15sp"
```